# Using $pull inside a loop returning null- Mongo/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

given two mongoose models having a field with embedded documents, referenced by ObjectId:

```
//Student.js

module.exports = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

documentId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},

courses: [
    {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Courses',
        required: true
    }
]})

//Course.js

module.exports = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

students: [
    {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Students'
    }
]})
```

I want to remove from Course.students array the given Student ObjectId as soon as I delete the the Student. For that purpose I've coded this:

```
removeStudent(documentId) {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            return Students.findOne({ documentId })
        })
        .then(student => {
            if (!student) throw Error('student does not exist')

            const coursesToBePulled = student.courses.toString().split(',')
            const studentMongoId = student._id.toString()

            async function updateStudentInCourses (coursesToBePulled, studentMongoId) {
                for (const item in coursesToBePulled) {
                    await Courses.findByIdAndUpdate(coursesToBePulled[item], { $pull: {'students': studentMongoId}}, {'new': true})
                }

                return Students.deleteOne({ documentId })
            }

            return updateStudentInCourses (coursesToBePulled, studentMongoId)
        })
}
```

The problem is when I use findByIdAndUpdate - $pull inside a loop it only works fine in the first iteration. For the other iterations instead of pulling the referenced id it places a null to the Courses.students array. After removing the student I'm getting this document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c4443f45c8c1d110671f7ed"),
"students" : [ 
    null
],
"name" : "curs 2",
"__v" : 0
```

}

So to recap, if a student is referenced in 3 courses, when I delete the student it is only removed from the Courses.students in the first iteration, the other 2 iterations it places a null inside Courses.students.

How can I make this work properly.

Thanks a lot in advance!